# How to parse or split string variable into multiple new variables in R

Tags: r, parsing, split

Saw an answer in Python similar for this question but not R so for the sake of being redundant since python is not in my wheel house. Data variable "PublicFilings" contains multiple values that I would like to split into 4 new variables. There are three basic outputs listed below but there will be different combinations of counts for Judgments, Liens and Suits, needless to say bankruptcy is yes no but I'd like that binary. Any thoughts on a simply approach for a data frame? Id can be used as a primary key the combination of No data as an initial output, inability to use comma to separate and desire to convert yes no to binary is throwing me off.

```
Existing Data 
Id   PublicFilings 
1    Bankruptcies: No, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0 
2    Bankruptcies: Yes, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0 
3    No Data
```

No Data implies there was no match to an entity and no Public Filing data was returned

```
Converted Data 
Id Bankruptcies Judgments Liens Suits 
1  0             0         0     0 
2  1             0         0     0 
3 Null           Null      Null  Null



   df1 <- 
  structure(list(TranId = 1:3, 
                 Name = c("ACME Five,","ACME","WALMART"),
                 Check = c("1234","1234","1235"), 
                 Entity = c("55555","55551","55556"),
                 Match =c("0","0","0"),
                 Score = c("50","60","NA"),
                 Date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02","2019-01-02"),
                 PublicFilings = c("Bankruptcies: No, Judgments: 0, Liens: 10, Suits: 0", 
                                   "Bankruptcies: Yes, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0", 
                                   "No Data"),
                 Controls =c("2015","2015","1998"),
                 NumEmpoyees = c("5","8","6"),
                 LOB = c("Retail, Food","Retail, Food","Retail, All"),
                 PayScore = c("40","42","NA"),
                 Primary = c("CEO","CEO","CFO"),
                 STARTYear = c("1982","1982","1965"),
                 SpecEvent = c("0","0","0"),
                 Filings =c("0","0","1"),
                 PayExp =c("","","1"
                 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

View(df1)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(PublicFilings, sep = ",\\s+") %>%
  separate(PublicFilings, into = c("key", "value"), sep=":\\s+") %>%
  mutate(key = na_if(key, "No Data"),
         value = as.integer(value %in%  c("Yes", "1"))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-`NA`)
View(df1)

    # A tibble: 3 x 20
  TranId Name  Check Entity Match Score Date  Controls NumEmpoyees LOB   PayScore Primary STARTYear SpecEvent Filings
   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  
1      1 ACME~ 1234  55555  0     50    2019~ 2015     5           Reta~ 40       CEO     1982      0         0      
2      2 ACME  1234  55551  0     60    2019~ 2015     8           Reta~ 42       CEO     1982      0         0      
3      3 WALM~ 1235  55556  0     NA    2019~ 1998     6           Reta~ NA       CFO     1965      0         1      
# ... with 5 more variables: PayExp <chr>, Bankruptcies <int>, Judgments <int>, Liens <int>, Suits <int>
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [9].
```

Comment: the solution needs to return all variables but split out PublicFilings into (4) new variables, missing values can exist in any variable except Id, Check, Entity, these are the only not null fields in the database

Comment: It is a warning message. Nothing to worry about.  I already knew that issue.  It is happening at the row with `No Data`

Comment: If you want to remove that warnings either can do a small change `df1 %>% mutate(PublicFilings = replace(PublicFilings, PublicFilings == 'No Data', 'NoData: No Data')) %>% separate_rows(PublicFilings, sep = ",\\s+") %>% separate(PublicFilings, into = c("key", "value"), sep=":\\s+") %>% mutate(key = na_if(key, "No Data"),
          value = as.integer(value %in%  c("Yes", "1"))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value)` or make some adjustments in the regex pattern

Comment: @akrun the split and pivot is not completing, no new fields are being created

Comment: Based on your dput output, it is completing for me

Comment: @akrun had to much fun troubleshooting this, had three issues in the PublicFilings field data quality that I did not previously identify and were not part of the sample data effecting like 30 of 13K total observations,in any event got to run finally TY

Comment: Great to hear that it is finally working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split the 'PublicFilings' at the `,` into 'long' format, then create two columns with `separate`, and reshape into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     separate_rows(PublicFilings, sep = ",\\s+") %>%
     separate(PublicFilings, into = c("key", "value"), sep=":\\s+") %>%
     mutate(key = na_if(key, "No Data"),
           value = as.integer(value %in%  c("Yes", "1"))) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%
     select(-`NA`)
#    Id Bankruptcies Judgments Liens Suits
#1  1            0         0     0     0
#2  2            1         0     0     0
#3  3           NA        NA    NA    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = 1:3, PublicFilings = c("Bankruptcies: No, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0", 
"Bankruptcies: Yes, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0", "No Data"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: hole new can of worms as pivot_wider function in a an updated version of R and I am unable to update my version, went down the road of trying to install install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse") based on different post now not recognizing dpylr package

Comment: OK just got tidyr and dplyr reinstalled and working, receiving this message akrun Error in spread(key, value) : object 'key' not found

Comment: tried a few different adjustments to spread substitution without any luck

Comment: @Ricky Can I know the `R`  version you have.  I am using `R  3.6.2`

Comment: 3.4.3 version control at a corporate level

Comment: @Ricky Maybe there is incomptability with the new tidyr version.  I have `tidyr 1.0.0`, but the `spread` should work as it is from older version

Comment: @Ricky Can you  try installing R 3.4.3 on a docker container (to check if this is reproducible) and install those packages and try the example.  I think it should work.  May be while inistalling the packages, it got corrupted.  Or could you remove those packages and do a fresh install

Comment: K been working to upgrade to 3.6, mission accomplished.  Now I can run pivot wider.  But receiving an error message -Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA.  The broader data set has variables with NA  that are preventing split

Comment: @Ricky Can you update your post with a small example that shows the error. i.e .using `dput` so that I get the structure right

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where `strsplit()` + `gsub()` are used

```
u <- strsplit(df$PublicFilings,split = ", ")
u[[which(lengths(u)==1)]] <- rep(NA, max(lengths(u)))
M <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) gsub(".*:\\s","",x), u))
M[M=="No"] <- 0
M[M=="Yes"] <- 1
dfout <- cbind(df[1],setNames(data.frame(M),gsub(":.*","",u[[which.max(lengths(u))]])))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Id Bankruptcies Judgments Liens Suits
1  1            0         0     0     0
2  2            1         0     0     0
3  3         <NA>      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:3, PublicFilings = c("Bankruptcies: No, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0", 
"Bankruptcies: Yes, Judgments: 0, Liens: 0, Suits: 0", "No Data"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: this solution is returning no data in the 4 new data variables vs NA when applied to the broader data set

Answer (score 0):

These answers were helpful in working out my problem- I'm saving my slightly different version which essentially does the same thing, captured into a function which could be polished further.

### ├ Function to extract ----

```
extract_keyval <- function(string, sep=","){
  string = gsub("No Data", "", string, ignore.case = T) # handle missing data
  key_value =  unlist(strsplit(string, split = sep)) # vector of key-value pairs  
  vars = gsub("(.*):\\s+.*", "\\1", key_value)    # extract variable name
  values = gsub(".*:\\s+(.*)", "\\1", key_value) # extract values
  values = gsub("yes", "1", values, ignore.case = T)
  values = gsub("no", "0", values, ignore.case = T)
  names(values) = vars # attach names to value
  return(values) # named vector 
  }
```

I typically use the `purrr` package to do the transformation back to a dataframe:

### ├ Tidyverse option ----

```
df1 %>% mutate(map_df(PublicFilings, ~extract_keyval(.x)))
```